# How can I load the css and jquery explicitly for the login screen

Tags: plugins

To avoid conflict I need to load the CSS and jquery explicitly for the login screen only and neither an admin nor on the frontend. Given that I have a custom login screen.

Comment: What does "I may also have a custom login screen as well" mean? Do you or don't you? How is it implemented? No one's going to be able to tell you how to loading something on a custom login screen if you don't explain what that is.

Comment: If it needs to be confirmed, then I have. My bad.

Comment: And? How was it implemented?

Comment: @Jacob Peattie By using the third party plugin for custom login URL change.

Comment: So you've only changed the URL to wp-login.php? You haven't created a separate login page or anything?

Comment: @Jacob Peattie NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load scripts and styles on the login page using the `login_enqueue_scripts` hook. You can use the same enqueue functions for scripts and styles that you'd use for other pages but they'll only load on the login page:

```
function wpse_330353_login_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'handle', '//example.com/url/to/script.js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'handle', '//example.com/url/to/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_330353_login_scripts' );
```

None of this would be affected by changing the URL of the login page.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. I forget it is available in WP. How stupid of me. :)  But since I don't have enough reputation "with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." You Know. But Thanks a lot. Answer accepted but no upvote for now.